# TypeScript Compile Suggestions (TS + gulp + karma)

Tags: typescript, gulp, karma-runner

I am trying to come up with a viable TypeScript build step that includes the following:

- Compile TypeScript (obviously)

  - ideally allowing the compiler to traverse the dependency tree
- Execute jasmine unit tests via karma
- No dependencies on IDE's (Visual Studio/WebStorm) to execute tests and output JS
- Ability to execute unit tests via WebStorm's run configurations
- Code coverage results based upon the TS code, not resulting JS

My current attempt involves using:

- gulp-tsc
- karma
- karma-typescript-preprocessor

I would prefer to only have to run the compilation steps once because as of now I have to do the pre-compile step for unit tests and the `build-ts` step below for output to my dist folder. I have tried using the `karma-typescript-pre-processor` with mixed results and poor performance (with tests, 16 seconds w/o 2 seconds).

Note: I have not yet attempted to tackle the code coverage aspect yet as I am not happy with the build/unit test solution I have in place.

The karma file I am currently using is

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      '../bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      '../bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      '../app/**/*_test.ts',
      {
        pattern: '../app/**/!(*_test).ts',
        included: false
      }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      '../typings/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts': ['typescript'],
      '../app/**/*.ts': ['typescript']
    },
    typescriptPreprocessor: {
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        target: 'ES5',
        noResolve: false
      },
      transformPath: function(path) {
        return path.replace(/\.ts$/, '.js');
      }
    },
    //reporters: ['progress', 'growl'],
    colors: true
  });
};
```

gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('build-ts', function () {
  return gulp.src(paths.ts)
    .pipe(tsc({
      noResolve: false,
      out: 'app.js',
      outDir: paths.dist.js,
      removeComments: true,
      //sourcePath: '../../app/ts',
      //sourcemap: true,
      target: 'ES5'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist.js))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

Comment: It sounds like the testing suite is your slow point, not the transpilation. You should look at your tests and see which ones take the longest. Maybe you can make them more efficient or faster? If you have tests that are timing-oriented, maybe you can introduce a Scheduler and do some deterministic testing?

Comment: Do you have a sample project to look at?

Comment: @SteveSloka You can take a look at this repo, the test is in app_tests.ts and the karma config file is located in the config directory (https://github.com/Brocco/ts-star-wars)

Comment: Why you are processing `../typings/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts` ? This is just a type definition.    Another option.. load tsconfig.json file to fill typescriptPreprocessor.options

Comment: @Ridermansb this question was from about 9 months ago (pre tsconfig.json).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gulp.watch to compile the typescript files on on save. That way when you run the tests the typescript is already compiled. The gulp-tsc module should have a guide for setting up incremental compiling.

Comment: While this doesn't quite handle my scenario fully it does align with what I am going with. gulp task to build JS (with sourcemaps for code coverage) I found out that I can use WebStorms run configs to pre-run compilation before executing unit tests against the outputted JS code. Thanks!